# Makefile ignoring @ to silent output

Tags: c, makefile

I have this Makefile:

```
CC          =   @gcc
RM          =   @rm

TARGET      =   test
PLUGINS_DIR =   plugins
PLUGINS_C   =   $(wildcard $(PLUGINS_DIR)/*.c)
PLUGINS_O   =   $(patsubst %.c,%.o, $(PLUGINS_C))
PLUGINS_SO  =   $(patsubst %.c,%.so, $(PLUGINS_C))

.PHONY: plugins

new: clean all

all: $(TARGET) $(PLUGINS_SO)

$(TARGET): $(TARGET).o
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ -g -Wall -std=gnu99 -ldl -Wl,--export-dynamic

$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.so: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@ -shared

$(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.o: $(PLUGINS_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< -o $@ -pedantic -g -Wall -std=c99 -fpic -I.

clean:
    $(RM) -rf $(TARGET) *.o *.a $(PLUGINS_O) $(PLUGINS_SO)
```

but the `clean` is still outputing a message! (`rm plugins/tt.o plugins/kk.o`)
If I remove the `@` in front of the `rm` then I get yet another message, besides the first one: `rm -rf test *.o *.a plugins/kk.o plugins/tt.o plugins/kk.so plugins/tt.so`

How can I make `make` completely silent? (Please, no `make` switches, just code inside the Makefile)

EDIT: Using make 4.0

Comment: I don't get any messages with your Makefile. (GNU make 3.81)

Comment: @OlafDietsche I'm on make 4.0

Comment: That rm of the .o files is make removing intermediate files. Not your rm command running. You need to tell make not to do that to avoid that message. See MadScientist's answer for a way to do that. Another way is using .PRECIOUS.

Comment: I wouldn't use `.PRECIOUS`.  That has other side-effects that you likely don't want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've got this wrong; I'll bet it's not your clean rule that's printing this.

Those object files are considered "intermediate targets", and as such make is deleting them for you automatically.  When it does, it prints that information so you know where they went.  The only way to stop that from happening is to define the `.SILENT:` special target (or give the `-s` flag but you said you didn't want to do that).

Or, you can ensure make doesn't consider those files to be intermediate (and thus not deleting them) by listing them as prerequisites, maybe:

```
all: $(TARGET) $(PLUGINS_SO) $(PLUGINS_O)
```

Comment: To be clear, `make clean` won't print that line, because it doesn't build those targets so it won't remove them.  It's only printed by `make all`.

Comment: Yup, that's the thing :)